# ¿cómo puedo relacional estas dos tablas? y por qué me da error en la sentencia de relación?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE ventas (
idventas INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
idcliente INT not null,
fechaVenta DATETIME,
cantidad INT,
precioVenta DECIMAL(5,3),
idempleado INT 

)

CREATE TABLE clientes(
id INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
nombre VARCHAR (45),
direccion VARCHAR (50),
email VARCHAR (50),
telefono INT, 
FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES **ventas** (idcliente)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu código deberá quedar así:

**Tabla clientes**

```
CREATE TABLE clientes( 
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
nombre VARCHAR (45), 
direccion VARCHAR (50), 
email VARCHAR (50), 
telefono INT );
```

**Tabla ventas**

```
CREATE TABLE ventas ( 
idventas INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
idcliente INT not null, 
fechaVenta DATETIME, 
cantidad INT, 
precioVenta DECIMAL(5,3), 
idempleado INT,
FOREIGN KEY(idcliente) REFERENCES clientes(id))
```

**Explicación**

- La tabla que contiene la llave primaria que es clientes, se declara primero
- La tabla ventas que contendrá la llave foránea se declara después
- La declaración de la `FK` o llave foránea debería ser así:

---

```
FOREIGN KEY(idcliente) REFERENCES clientes(id)
```

- Pues tu llave foránea `idCliente` es la columna directamente relacionada con la columna `id` de la tabla `clientes`